# correct usage has or have?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, plural-forms, singular

> As discussed yesterday, this numbers **have** to increase..

In the above sentence, Is it correct to use have instead of has. Numbers are always described as singular. In this sentence have is used and what are the different scenario to use has and have.

In case we re frame this sentence to as discussed yesterday, this number ....to increase

Answer (score 1):

In the above sentence, there is another mistake:

> this numbers

"this" is singular

"numbers" is plural

So depending on the intention, you can have:

> As discussed yesterday, **this number has** to increase..

or

> As discussed yesterday, **these numbers have** to increase..